# Creating a chart of directory structure on a complicated Linux server

Tags: linux, directory, directory-structure

Im part of a development team for a certain server. Our project has a lot of old/legacy stuff, including code and design, and for this iteration at least it will remain like this. The server is Debian 7 I think, and its directory layout is quite custom. Most of the directories have been modified, moved, new-created, linked, mounted from external devices using NAS, etc.

We are trying to create some documentation for this server. Is there a tool that can automatically map out directories on a Linux machine and create a chart/graphic of them, while keeping important information about their linkage, mounting, structure?

Comment: Try using the `tree` command. Use `tree --help` to use the other options you can use

Comment: Thats the way im currently doing it, using tree. But I hoped for a better way, that would also make it more visually appealing to later post somewhere as part of documentation @GMaster